# How can I wait for a network call in Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

If I'm reading this correctly, it should be possible to read the network tab of Chrome dev tools using Selenium.

I spent a few hours trying to set this up yesterday and got nowhere. This is for UI tests so what I'm trying to do is:

- Set a value in a filter by clicking on it
- Wait for GET that fires to return
- Set a value in another filter by clicking
- ...

At the moment, I have a hard-coded 1 second wait that I am very unhappy with. If there's no wait in there, the test gets ahead of itself and fails.

Help please!

Comment: What selenium sees is the html of a page, I don't think you can read the network tab of the devtools. Maybe with pyautogui you can do something

Comment: If the GET is fired via JS, you want to use a webdriverwait.  It will wait the amount of time it takes for an expected condition to be met: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/  A standard GET call will automatically be waited for. (non-js)

Comment: @pcalkins It doesn't seem  like a weddriverwait would work here as I'm not waiting on any page elements to load. I'm only waiting on the GET request to complete. Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: if there's no indication in the DOM that the GET request is complete it wouldn't work.  The is a dev tools protocol, and the halfway implemented "Bidi" interfaces:  https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/chrome_devtools/  A lot of it is undocumented or just not yet supported.  (there's a lot going on in the browser's inspector.)  Include the code that makes the GET call... there may be a way to at least get the XHR headers or to find what happens when the call returns.

Answer (score 1):

I had to switch part of my application to python to use selenium wire to get this done, I am not sure how to do it in c# but this was super simple in python. It offers a ton of control over Network requests and responses. Just wanted to put it here in case this is an option for you. I just made my c# execute a python script that runs its own instance of chrome.

Here are some docs:

https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/#example-mock-a-response

https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire#all-options

Selenium Wire is super powerful and the easiest way I found to manipulate or execute actions based on network traffic. Below are two examples. One waiting for a network call. And the other intercepting a network request with a custom response.

```py
from seleniumwire import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.wait_for_request('/signup/lifeline/nv/status', 60)
```

This will wait up to 60 seconds for that request before timing out.

```py
from seleniumwire import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

Endpoint = "/endpoint"
def interceptor(request):
    if 'Endpoint' in request.url:
        request.create_response(
            status_code=200,
            headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},  # Optional headers dictionary
            body=EndPointResponse)

self.driver.request_interceptor = interceptor
```

This will intercept the request when it is made and replace the response with whatever you would like.